# AccessInit: hash collision: 22 for both 1 and 1

Tags: python, ipython, python-imaging-library

I'm doing an exercise from Udacity > [Deep Learning](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/udacity/1_notmnist.ipynb), which requires the following imports:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import sys
import tarfile
from IPython.display import display, Image
from scipy import ndimage
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from six.moves.urllib.request import urlretrieve
from six.moves import cPickle as pickle
```

all my train and test data have been downloaded, found and verified, but when I reach **Problem 1** on the above link and run my script, I get:

> AccessInit: hash collision: 22 for both 1 and 1

I have commented out `from IPython.display import display, Image`, and tried:

```
from PIL import Image
```

but I get the same error. and also, instead of the latter import, I have tried:

```
import PIL.Image
sys.modules['Image'] = PIL.Image
```

to no avail.

Any clues?